# How to find the tomcat automatic shutdown reason by catalina.out

Tags: java, spring-mvc, tomcat, tomcat7

recently, tomcat occur several times on automatic shutdown. but not find the reason by catalina.out

Server:linux(1 core cpu, 1G memory)

tomcat: 7.0.65

tomcat server.xml add jvm setting:
JAVA_OPTS="-server -Xms256m -Xmx512m -XX:PermSize=256M -XX:MaxPermSize=512m"

catalina.out

```
2016-05-17 00:31:55 -173311 [http-bio-8080-exec-5] DEBUG   - ==> Parameters: 3(String)
2016-05-17 00:31:55 -173313 [http-bio-8080-exec-5] DEBUG   - Closing non transactional SqlSession [org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession@5503fcfc]
May 17, 2016 2:43:14 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause
INFO: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
May 17, 2016 2:43:14 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause
INFO: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
May 17, 2016 2:43:14 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService stopInternal
INFO: Stopping service Catalina
2016-05-17 02:43:14 -8036625 [localhost-startStop-2] INFO    - Closing WebApplicationContext for namespace 'springMvc-servlet': startup date [Tue May 17 00:29:22 CST 2016]; parent: Root WebApplicationContext
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
May 17, 2016 2:43:14 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase clearReferencesJdbc
SEVERE: The web application [/legoms] registered the JDBC driver [com.alibaba.druid.proxy.DruidDriver] but failed to unregister it when the web application was stopped. To prevent a memory leak, the JDBC Driver has been forcibly unregistered.
May 17, 2016 2:43:14 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase clearReferencesJdbc
SEVERE: The web application [/legoms] registered the JDBC driver [com.mysql.jdbc.Driver] but failed to unregister it when the web application was stopped. To prevent a memory leak, the JDBC Driver has been forcibly unregistered.
May 17, 2016 2:43:14 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase clearReferencesThreads
SEVERE: The web application [/legoms] appears to have started a thread named [Abandoned connection cleanup thread] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
2016-05-17 02:43:14 -8051975 [localhost-startStop-2] INFO    - Closing WebApplicationContext for namespace 'springMvc-servlet': startup date [Tue May 17 00:29:10 CST 2016]; parent: Root WebApplicationContext
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
May 17, 2016 2:43:14 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase clearReferencesJdbc
SEVERE: The web application [] registered the JDBC driver [com.alibaba.druid.proxy.DruidDriver] but failed to unregister it when the web application was stopped. To prevent a memory leak, the JDBC Driver has been forcibly unregistered.
May 17, 2016 2:43:14 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase clearReferencesJdbc
SEVERE: The web application [] registered the JDBC driver [com.mysql.jdbc.Driver] but failed to unregister it when the web application was stopped. To prevent a memory leak, the JDBC Driver has been forcibly unregistered.
May 17, 2016 2:43:14 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase clearReferencesThreads
SEVERE: The web application [] appears to have started a thread named [Abandoned connection cleanup thread] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
May 17, 2016 2:43:14 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks
SEVERE: The web application [] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [org.apache.shiro.util.ThreadContext.InheritableThreadLocalMap] (value [org.apache.shiro.util.ThreadContext$InheritableThreadLocalMap@6ae24d54]) and a value of type [java.util.HashMap] (value [{org.apache.shiro.util.ThreadContext_SECURITY_MANAGER_KEY=org.apache.shiro.web.mgt.DefaultWebSecurityManager@2f42fc9e, org.apache.shiro.util.ThreadContext_SUBJECT_KEY=org.apache.shiro.web.subject.support.WebDelegatingSubject@56d7014f}]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.
May 17, 2016 2:43:14 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol stop
INFO: Stopping ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
May 17, 2016 2:43:14 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol stop
INFO: Stopping ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
May 17, 2016 2:43:14 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy
INFO: Destroying ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
May 17, 2016 2:43:14 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy
INFO: Destroying ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason your Tomcat server could be shutting down is due to an operating system update requiring your JVM to start (possibly a kernel update). I would start by looking in your operating system logs beginning with yum or whatever package manager your system is using to see if there were any updates and what it was doing when your server stopped.

This has happened to me quite a few times.

Comment: thanks. but how to find out which system log files? use `ls -l /var/log/`, not fond recent update log file

Comment: There shouldn't be many logs to sort through, I don't think searching is necessary in this instance since many system files roll and you're looking for a specific date/time. For example, on a centos system you may have a messages, yum.log, and secure files.